# Динамическое создание и добавление елементов html с помощью dom стуктуры

Tags: javascript, dom

При нажатии на "add test" внутри `div` с `id` `test_container` появляется `div` с классом `q`. Внутри которого появляется `input` и сбоку `button` с классом `add_ans`. При нажатии на этот `button` внутри `div` с классом `q` появляются `input` с классом `answer_input` - как варианты ответов.

Проблема в том, что `input` для вариантов ответов добавляются, только, в случае клика на первый `button`, который был создан статически, А мне нужно чтобы с каждого `button` соответствующим `input` который создаётся динамически запускалась эта функция.

```js
function add_test() {
  var question = document.getElementsByClassName("question_container");
  var q = document.createElement("div");
  q.setAttribute("class", "q");

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML = "Add question";

  q.appendChild(span);

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("class", "question_input");

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.setAttribute("class", "add_ans");
  button.innerHTML = "+";

  q.appendChild(input);
  q.appendChild(button);

  for (var i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
    question[i].appendChild(q);
  }
}

function add_answer() {
  var q_ans = document.getElementsByClassName("q");
  var question_container = document.getElementsByClassName("question_container");

  var input_ans = document.createElement("input");
  input_ans.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input_ans.setAttribute("class", "answer_input");

  //alert(question_container[0].children[1]);
  for (var i = 0; i < question_container.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < q_ans.length; k++)
      question_container[i].children[k].appendChild(input_ans);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#test_container {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.q {
  display: inline-block;
}

.question_container span {
  color: red;
}

.question_container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="test_container">
  <button onclick="add_test()">Add test</button>
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="q">
      <span>Add question</span>
      <input type="text" class="question_input" name="question" />
      <button class="add_ans" onclick="add_answer()"> + </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Save test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про [bubbling](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling).

Слушайте событие `click` на общем родителе. Проверяйте что кликнули по правильному элементу и выполняйте добавление ответа.

```js
function add_test() 
{
    
        


        var question=document.getElementsByClassName("question_container");
        var q=document.createElement("div");
        q.setAttribute("class","q");


        var span=document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML="Add question";

        q.appendChild(span);

        var input=document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type","text");
        input.setAttribute("class", "question_input");


        var button=document.createElement("button");
        button.setAttribute("class", "add_ans");
        button.innerHTML="+";

        q.appendChild(input);
        q.appendChild(button);

        

    for (var i = 0; i<question.length; i++) 
    {

        question[i].appendChild(q);
    }





}




function add_answer( button ) 
{
    var q_ans = button.parentNode

    var input_ans=document.createElement("input");
    input_ans.setAttribute("type","text");
    input_ans.setAttribute("class", "answer_input");
    
    q_ans.insertBefore( input_ans, button );
         

}
    
document.body.addEventListener('click', function( ev ){
  var node = ev.target;
   if( ! node.classList.contains('add_ans') ) return;
   
   add_answer( node );
   
}, true)
```

```html
<title>Document</title>
<body>
<div id = "test_container">

  <button onclick="add_test()">Add test</button>

   <div class="question_container">
     <div class="q">
        <span>Add question</span>
        <input type="text" name="question">
        <button class = "add_ans" >+</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<button>Save test</button>
</body>
```